# Control the environment of nested calls to source()

Tags: r, metaprogramming, drake-r-package

In [this new set of features](https://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual/projects.html#safer-interactivity), I am trying to steer [`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) away from the user's global environment. This is challenging because users can define arbitrarily nested code files. Let's say a user defines files `packages.R`, `functions.R`, and `master.R` as below.

```r
writeLines("library(MASS)", "packages.R")
writeLines("util <- function() {'utility'}", "functions.R")
writeLines(c("source('packages.R')", "source('functions.R')"), "master.R")

cat(readLines("packages.R"), sep = "\n")
#> library(MASS)

cat(readLines("functions.R"), sep = "\n")
#> util <- function() {'utility'}

cat(readLines("master.R"), sep = "\n")
#> source('packages.R')
#> source('functions.R')
```

As the developer, I am looking for a way to run `master.R` such that none of the new data objects ends up in the global environment. My initial attempts do not succeed.

### Current behavior

```r
envir <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
source("master.R", local = envir)

ls(envir)
#> character(0)

ls()
#> [1] "envir" "util"
```

### Desired result

```r
envir <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
# Run master.R

ls(envir)
#> [1] "util"

ls()
#> [1] "envir"
```

### Constraints

- I am not allowed to modify the code inside `packages.R`, `functions.R`, or `master.R`. As the developer, I only have control over the `# Run master.R` line above.
- Sourcing the files in the global environment and then manually copying to a different environment is fraught with closure and lexical scoping pitfalls, so I would strongly prefer to stay away from that.

Comment: You can redefine `source()` in your `envir` to source to that specific environment: `envir$source <- function(..., local=envir) source(..., local=local)`. But otherwise if you need that type of isolation, you're probably going to have to spawn some other processes. Things in R aren't really set up to easily avoid the global environment.

Comment: Disappointing, but not surprising. Fortunately, in [this use case](https://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual/projects.html#safer-interactivity), we are already spawning fresh processes. This gets us most of the way there, but [some issues](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/675#issuecomment-458222414) still seem best avoided by avoiding the global environment altogether.